# add row at the top of the gridview in c#

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms

How do i add new row at the top of the Gridview ??
Here is the code:

```
<FooterTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="btnsave" runat="server" Text="Add New" 
        class="btn icon-btn btn-success btn-sm" 
        OnClientClick="return GetGridFooterRowvalues()" 
        OnClick="btnsave_Click" />
</FooterTemplate>
```

here is the image:
[image]
I want at the top of the grid add row in Item template field..

I want at the top of the grid i.e. instead of last row at the first row i want add row..any suggestions??

Comment: Can you re-format you post to make it readable? What code you have written so far to solve this issue?

Comment: <FooterTemplate>
                                                                        <asp:Button ID="btnsave" runat="server" Text="Add New" class="btn icon-btn btn-success btn-sm" OnClientClick="return GetGridFooterRowvalues()"
                                                                            OnClick="btnsave_Click" />
                                                                    </FooterTemplate>

Comment: And what code you have written so far to add new row?

Answer (score 0):

This example shows how to insert new row at the top of the dgv (to the binding dgv, dataSource is a dataTable):

```
DataTable table;
public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  //initializing new dataTable and its columns
  //and setting the dataSource property to dgv:
  table = new DataTable("myTable");
  table.Columns.Add("column 1", typeof(int));
  table.Columns.Add("column 2", typeof(string));
  table.Rows.Add(1, "item 1");
  table.Rows.Add(2, "item 2");
  dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
  dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //How to insert new row at the top:
  DataRow dr = table.NewRow();
  table.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);
}
```

Comment: Sir my issue is i want at the top of the gridview i.e. at the top row of the gridview add row with add new button...